# Start Session ICEauthority

Tags: login

Today I can't enter in my session, Ubuntu say me "Could not update /home/user/.ICEauthority"

I looking for in internet and I do this step

```
chown user:user /home/user/.ICEauthority
chmod 644 /home/user/.ICEauthority
```

But didn't solved the problem.

Comment: `mv` away that file and try again

Comment: I just do that and....nothing

Answer (score 0):

If someone does have the same problem like susana, i think i have solved it with

```
iceauth -i -b
```

when logged in as user with strg+alt+f1